# Return value is Completion Record?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In the specification, there are a lot of records like `return value`. Is it possible to state exactly that all records of the type `return value` return a Completion Record. In the specification there is a paragraph that sounds like this:

> **6.2.3.2 Implicit Completion Values**
>
> The algorithms of this specification often implicitly return Completion Records whose
>   [[Type]] is normal. Unless it is otherwise obvious from the context,
>   an algorithm statement that returns a value that is not a Completion
>   Record, such as:
>
> `1. Return "Infinity".`
>
> means the same thing as:
>
> `1. Return NormalCompletion("Infinity").`
>
> However, if the value expression
>   of a “return” statement is a Completion Record construction literal,
>   the resulting Completion Record is returned. If the value expression
>   is a call to an abstract operation, the “return” statement simply
>   returns the Completion Record produced by the abstract operation.
>
> The abstract operation Completion(completionRecord) is used to
>   emphasize that a previously computed Completion Record is being
>   returned. The Completion abstract operation takes a single argument,
>   completionRecord, and performs the following steps:
>
> `1. Assert: completionRecord is a Completion Record.`
>
> `2. Return completionRecord as the Completion Record of this abstract operation.`
>
> A “return” statement without a value in an algorithm step means the
>   same thing as:
>
> `1. Return NormalCompletion(undefined).`
>
> Any reference to a Completion
>   Record value that is in a context that does not explicitly require a
>   complete Completion Record value is equivalent to an explicit
>   reference to the [[Value]] field of the Completion Record value unless
>   the Completion Record is an abrupt completion.

And here there is a question! Sometimes the return values must be a particular data type. For example, http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-objectcreate `6. Return obj.` So are we returning an object or Completion Record?

Comment: A completion record, according to the thing you quoted. `NormalCompletion(obj)`.

Comment: “Any reference to a Completion Record value that is in a context that does not explicitly require a complete Completion Record value is equivalent to an explicit reference to the [[Value]] field of the Completion Record value unless the Completion Record is an abrupt completion.”

Comment: @Ry︁ Any return is a Completion Record? And look at that http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-ordinarytoprimitive `1. Assert: Type(O) is Object.` Here is the statement that it is an object. But if the receipt of `O` was Completion Record. How it to understand? If we get Completion Record on return, how do we get another type of data from it? For example: a number, a string, an object.

Comment: @Ry I do not understand what it means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So are we returning an object or Completion Record?

The section you've quoted does indeed explain this:

> [...] an algorithm statement that returns a value that is not a Completion Record, such as:
>
> 1. Return "Infinity".
>
> means the same thing as:
>
> 1. Return NormalCompletion("Infinity").

So applying that to

> 6. Return obj.

`obj` here is "a newly created object" which means it is not a completion record. That means that as the above statement says, it is treated like

> 6. Return NormalCompletion(obj).

Secondly:

> Any return is a Completion Record? And look at that ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-ordinarytoprimitive 1. Assert: Type(O) is Object. Here is the statement that it is an object. But if the receipt of O was Completion Record. How it to understand? If we get Completion Record on return, how do we get another type of data from it?

The text you quoted answers that with:

> Any reference to a Completion Record value that is in a context that does not explicitly require a complete Completion Record value is equivalent to an explicit reference to the [[Value]] field

In that context, `Type(O)` is treated as `Type(O.[[Value]])`

Comment: Any return is a Completion Record? And look at that http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-ordinarytoprimitive `1. Assert: Type(O) is Object.` Here is the statement that it is an object. But if the receipt of `O` was Completion Record. How it to understand? If we get Completion Record on return, how do we get another type of data from it? For example: a number, a string, an object.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: And what does it mean: `Any reference to a Completion Record value`. What kind of type `reference` talking about?

Comment: In that context it is "Any mention of a Completion Record value in the spec`

Comment: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-getvalue would be one example. `V` is usually a completion record, but it is then used in the function as a general value.

Comment: If I understand correctly if a value of a particular type is required from the Complete Record, the value of the [[Value]] field is passed?